# Fat storage / A fat storage

Tags: adjectives, determiners, uncountable-nouns

Do I need a determiner before uncountable nouns modified by adjectives and mentioned for the first time?

> Insulin causes fat storage / a fat storage.
>
> Cells burn sugar and create energy storage / an energy storage.

(I know that I can use "the" if I mentioned the concept before and I want to refer to it but I am not sure about the "a/an").

Thanks =)

Comment: The answer is the same either way, but *fat* here is a noun, not an adjective.

Comment: @snailboat I'm not sure you're right about that. I believe *storage* is the noun here, and *fat* an adjective indicating the type of storage.

Comment: Look up *attributive noun*.

Comment: @snailboat Hmmm, "a fat storage" would sound wrong to me in most circumstances.

Comment: @Araucaria Right, same here.  Did you misread my comment as suggesting that both of the OP's options are equally good?  Allow me to clarify.  When I wrote my comment, I was saying "The answer is the same whether you consider *fat* an adjective or a noun, but *fat* here is a noun, not an adjective."

Comment: From [the Wiktionary entry for **attributive noun**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attributive_noun): `a noun used as an adjective` - as I read this, and applied to the phrase "fat storage", it means: "The word *fat* has both noun and adjective definitions; in this instance the word *fat* carries the meaning of the noun definition, but its part of speech in this sentence is adjective.

Comment: It's unfortunate that Wiktionary has such low-quality definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid -'no' article it takes.

Storage is an [uncountable noun](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/storage?q=storage), so it goes here without any article

> *Insulin causes **fat storage***

You are right in placing the *definite* article once that 'storage' is mentioned. So,...

> *Insulin causes **fat storage**. The storage, over the period, blocks tiny arteries and damages them.*